# Confusion in the use of byte variable

Tags: variables

A byte stores an 8-bit unsigned number, from 0 to 255.

I can understand the following line:

```
byte b = B10010;  // "B" is the binary formatter (B10010 = 18 decimal)
```

But I also saw a use such as:

```
volatile byte state = LOW;
```

What does the last line mean here? Is that special for Arduino?
I mean LOW is not a 8 bit unsigned number. LOW is not a number here.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably somewhere else, like this:

```
#define LOW 0
```

Which means the pre-processor turns your line from this:

```
volatile byte state = LOW;
```

into this:

```
volatile byte state = 0;
```

There is nothing arduino-specific here, just the use of standard C/C++ features.

Answer (score 2):

It is common practise in C/C++ to define certain much-used constants at the beginning of the code.

```
#define true 1
```

this means that every time you write true in your code, the compiler will see it as 1.

The arduino IDE comes with a few constants predefined:

- true = 1
- false = 0
- HIGH = 1
- LOW = 0
- ...

Comment: in C++ `true` and `false` are already keywords, why would one try to  `#define` them?

Comment: @jfpoilpret Perhaps if one is not using C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you can do

```
int blarb = 12;
#define wibble 73
```

you can do

```
int FOO = 73;
#define BINKY 99
```

or even

```
int LOW = 0;
#define HIGH 1
```

So in the line

```
volatile byte state = LOW;
```

someone has created some sort of numerical constant with the name `LOW`.

You can read all about various constants provided for you [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constants).